# Complex Unbounded function, reciprocal has a zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

Just to check a concept in Complex Analysis.

Let's say $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an unbounded (holomorphic) function on the disk $\{z:|z|<r\}$.

Can we say $\frac{1}{f}$ has a zero on the disk $\{z:|z|<r\}$?

Intuitively, $1/\infty=0$, but I am not sure whether that holds rigorously or not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $r=1$ and $f(z) = 1/(z-1)$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{f}$ can never be $0$ if $f$ maps to $\mathbb{C}$, maybe you mean $f$ maps from the riemann sphere to itself? holomorphic still makes sense but then you have to be careful about the points where $f(z)=\infty$.

Comment: I see... Thanks. I guess all we can say is $1/f$ is arbitrarily close to zero, but it can never be zero.

Comment: Yes, that follows immediately from the fact that $f$ is unbounded. If we assume $f \neq 0$ on the disc in question we even have a sequence $(z_n)$of points in the disc converging to a point on the boundary of the disc for which $f(z_n) \to \infty$ or equivalently $\frac{1}{f(z_n)} \to 0$.